# Container panels and JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, absolutelayout

I'm working on GUI and I'm an amateur programmer. I have a problem with this code. I can't see anything on the frame.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 1366, 768);
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.setLayout(null);

Container midPanel = new JPanel();
midPanel.setLayout(null);
Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(700, 700);
midPanel.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);

            .....

Container k1 = new JPanel();
k1.setSize(50, 700);
k1.setLocation(0, 0);
k1.setLayout(new GridLayout(rowNum, 1));

k1.setVisible(true);

midPanel.add(k1);

            .......

Dimension jspD = new Dimension(500,500); 
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(midPanel);
jsp.setPreferredSize(jspD);
jsp.setLocation(0, 0);
jsp.setVisible(true);

contentPane.add(jsp);
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you add the scrollPane to the frame?

Comment: anything not seen on frame

Comment: contentPane.add(jsp);

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
midPanel.setLayout(null);
```

You should always use  **Layout Managers**, never ever remove the layout for any reason, except if you had an assignment required to use absolute layout (*null* layout).

The problem is with absolute layout , you have to specify the location of components inside the panel by `component.setBounds(x,y,width,height)` every time adding a component, otherwise, it won't be visible.

See this tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).